# Backbone listenTo() to change nested object

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

Is it possible to make a controller listen to changes in nested object. The program runs fine when listened to the parent object 'resultSetParameters'. However when i make changes front-end to the nested object 'properties' the controller doesn't recogonize those changes, therefor i am trying to make it listen to the child/nested object 'properties'.

The parent object with nested child object 'properties':

```
resultSetParameters = new Backbone.Model({

            activeFilter: false,

            filter: {

                address: '',

                filterAmountFrom: '',

                filterAmountTo: '',

                properties: {}

            }

        });
```

The controller:

```
    var controller = {};

    _.extend(controller, Backbone.Events);
```

The working listenTo() which dont recognize updated on its child objects:

```
controller.listenTo(resultSetParameters, 'change', function () {

        fetchCoaches();

        cache.resultSetParameters.coach = resultSetParameters;

    });
```

I want to do something like this:

```
controller.listenTo(resultSetParameters.filter.properties, 'change', function () {



        console.log("Filter just changed");



    });
```

Comment: look into backbone deep model plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resultSetParameters.trigger('change');